# Проверить градиент для обратного распространения ошибки

Tags: машинное-обучение, нейронные-сети

Как можно понять, пробрасывается ли ошибка для определенного блока, если мы не знаем ничего про см блок, а хотим только проверить, опрокидывается ли градиент в bacpropogation?

Comment: Покажите какой-нибудь код, пожалуйста. Что конкретно вы имеете ввиду? Например, если обычно мы используем аналитические методы для расчёта обратного распространения, то также [есть численные методы](https://www.coursera.org/lecture/machine-learning/gradient-checking-Y3s6r). Можно проверить ими.

Comment: Конкретного кола нет. Просто нать блок чёрный ящик . И я хочу проверить он он привыильно считает градиент для обратного распространения ошибки.

Comment: Без конкретного кода нам сложно будет вам помочь. Например, вы можете изобрести собственный черный ящик.